# how to fix this issue "Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.Goodiebag:PinView:v1.3."

Tags: java, android, github, sdk

when i add dependencies in gradle it show error:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.Goodiebag:PinView:v1.3.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.Goodiebag:PinView:v1.3.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.Goodiebag:PinView:v1.3.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.Goodiebag:PinView:v1.3.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.Goodiebag:PinView:v1.3.
>   Open File
>   Show Details

my dependencies here:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.github.Goodiebag:PinView:v1.3'//this one is showing error

    /*implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4'*/
    /*implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'*/
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

here is my build.gradle(project Cogniable)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{ url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/GoodieBag/Pinview and if that doesn't explain it, show the rest of your build.gradle showing _where_ the dependency repos are set.

Comment: i updated my repos @jdv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your internet connect is on
2. Your android studio is not in offline mode

If above two are correct then do this :
add this `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` in your **build.gradle (Project Level)**
under repositories block which is under allprojects block, so your build.gradle allprojects block code should look like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: my android studio was in offline mode, now its working..thanks bro